# SSRS Report Wizard

Tags: reporting-services, report, wizard

Was wondering if there is any way to get back into the Report Wizard in SSRS, after completing it. I find myself often wanting to tweak something, but can't see any way to get back into it without restarting everything from scratch - very annoying! Does anyone know a way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think it is possible to get back to the wizard without making a new report.